# Query optimization: JOINs in subquery

Tags: sql, performance, join, subquery, query-optimization

Given the following query:

```
SELECT [CustomerID], [CustomerName],[CustomerAddress],[CustomerPhone]
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID IN
    (SELECT CustomerID FROM Buys b 
    JOIN CarService cs ON cs.SoldCarNum=b.SoldCarNum        
    JOIN GarageWorkers gw ON cs.WorkerNum=gw.WorkerNum 
    WHERE YEAR(cs.ServiceDate) BETWEEN 2015 AND 2016
    GROUP BY CustomerID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT gw.GarageID)>= 7)
```

Is there any possible way to make it more efficient? I don't like the JOINs but I don't see how I can get rid of them.

**Edit:**

I use Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that this is your query:

```
SELECT [CustomerID], [CustomerName], [CustomerAddress], [CustomerPhone]
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.CustomerID IN (SELECT b.CustomerID
                       FROM Buys b JOIN
                            CarService cs
                            ON cs.SoldCarNum = b.SoldCarNum JOIN    
                            GarageWorkers gw
                            ON cs.WorkerNum = gw.WorkerNum 
                       WHERE YEAR(cs.ServiceDate) BETWEEN 2015 AND 2016
                       GROUP BY CustomerID
                       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT gw.GarageID) >=  7
                      );
```

This would appear to be customers who had seven or more cars service their car in 2015 and 2016.  First, I would change the date comparison to use real dates rather than `YEAR()` (so indexes can be used).  This looks like:

```
SELECT [CustomerID], [CustomerName], [CustomerAddress], [CustomerPhone]
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.CustomerID IN (SELECT b.CustomerID
                       FROM Buys b JOIN
                            CarService cs
                            ON cs.SoldCarNum = b.SoldCarNum JOIN    
                            GarageWorkers gw
                            ON cs.WorkerNum = gw.WorkerNum 
                       WHERE cs.ServiceDate >= '2015-01-01' AND
                             cs.ServiceDate < '2017-01-01'
                       GROUP BY b.CustomerID
                       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT gw.GarageID) >=  7
                      );
```

Next, you want indexes.  I would recommend:

- `CarService(ServiceDate, SoldCarNum, WorkerNum)`
- `Buys(SoldCarNum, CustomerId)`
- `GarageWorkers(WorkerNum, GarageID)`

These indexes "cover" the subquery, meaning that they have all the columns in the subquery.

You don't mention the database.  In some databases, replacing the `IN (<subquery>)` with `JOIN (<subquery>)` would also often improve performance.

Comment: Thank you. I use Microsoft SQL Server. Does that give you any more ideas of how to improve the query?

Comment: In my case (MSSQL) would the JOIN (<subquery>) help?

Comment: @Alon . . . I am actually not sure, but I would write it as a `JOIN` rather than `IN`, just because it is more likely to be optimized in more databases.